# creating all csv files in a folder to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, create-table

I'm trying to debug my code for hours and I cant seem to find a solution. 
I'm trying to put all my .csv files from a folder to mysql database and it seems I'm having an error regarding my query. My query is alright(I think) but the error is saying: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server.....

Anyone can help on how to do this? :(

Here's my code:

```
<?php

 $server = "localhost";
      $username = "root";
      $pass = "";
      $dbname = "test";


      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$pass);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



$files = glob('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\*.csv');
$table = glob('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\*.csv');

foreach($files as $filename){

// get structure from csv and insert db
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$handle = fopen($filename,'r');
// first row, structure
if ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) === FALSE ) {
echo "Cannot read from csv $filename";die();
}
$fields = array();
$field_count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($data); $i++) {
$f = strtolower(trim($data[$i]));
if ($f) {
    // normalize the field name, strip to 20 chars if too long
    $f = substr(preg_replace ('/[^0-9a-z]/', '_', $f), 0, 20);
    $field_count++;
    $fields[] = $f.' VARCHAR(255)';
  }
}
}

foreach($table as $tablename){

$sqlcreate = $conn->prepare("CREATE TABLE $tablename (" . implode(', ', $fields) . ')');
$sqlcreate->execute();

//echo "Create Table success" . "<br /><br />";
//$db->query($sql);
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) !== FALSE ) {
$fields = array();
for($i=0;$i<$field_count; $i++) {
    $fields[] = '\''.addslashes($data[$i]).'\'';
}
$sqlinsert = $conn->prepare("Insert into $tablename values(" . implode(', ', 
$fields) . ')');
 $sqlinsert->execute();
//echo "Insert Table success" ; 

}
}
fclose($handle);
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',FALSE);

      echo "Sucess"

?>
```

Comment: `MariaDB` or `mysql`?

Comment: its mysql but the error is saying MariaDB hmmm :/ 
but I'm 100% sure I'm using mysql

Comment: Echo your SQL queries

Comment: @Michael O. I can't echo my SQL queries.... I'm getting this error message:
: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':\Users\HP\Desktop\ACC.DBF.csv (id VARCHAR(255), name VARCHAR(255), owner VARCHA' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php(47): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php on line 47

Comment: Make query strings without perparing and executing and echo them. For example: `$temp="CREATE TABLE $tablename (" . implode.......;` `echo $temp;`

Comment: @MichaelO. well it showed me some results that I want to execute to my database 
since I have two(for now) csv files in a  folder I was able to echo the query along with their fields... 
CREATE TABLE C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DBFFiles\672VER.DBF.csv
CREATE TABLE C:\Users\HP\Desktop\DBFFiles\ACC.DBF.csv

Comment: So, you are creating tables in MySQL as files? You are doing it wrong.

Comment: ooooohhh... but I only want to get the filename.. not the whole directory... why did it resulted to that... hm :/

Comment: Also, .DBF extension is related to dBase.

Comment: about that .dbf .... I just converted those using a vbscript I made.... for converting all dbf files in a folder to .csv  
so yeah... its still a .csv